# Adobe Photoshop 'Save As' Action

Tags: action, photoshop

I'm trying to save a large number of images in JPEG format. Each file combines 2 layers visible on the screen. To achieve this, I've recorded a simple action that saves the file as X.jpg. I don't mind the fact that it saves the next file as X copy.jpg, but the problem occurs when trying to save the 3rd image (and other consecutive images), as instead of creating another file, it replaces the previous X copy.jpg file with the 3rd image.

Does anyone know how to instruct it to keep creating new files instead of rewriting the X copy one?

Comment: Hi Art z, welcome to Stack Overflow . Your question seems off-topic for this site as it doesn't directly involve code, nor tools used primarily for programming. For this type of question you'll have a greater chance of getting an answer over at [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). It has similar questions as yours tagged under [photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop).

Comment: You could try utilizing Photoshop's _Batch_ Processing feature which allows you to choose a custom Action, for instance refer to [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/40795/controlling-save-name-when-using-action-to-batch-process-and-save). When configuring your batch process to handle _File Naming_ choose a _2/4 Digit Serial Number_ to make the filenames unique.